# How can I formally prove the following function is bounded?

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

I have recently started learning Calculus, and upon stumbling on the following question, I got a little stuck.

The question:
Determine if the function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ given by $f(x) = {x\sin(x)\over |x| + 1}$ is bounded and provide a justification (a proof).

Since I know that the denominator is never going to be a negative number, I have tried to get rid of the absolute signs $|x| + 1 ≥ 1$  and solve for x like so: 
$-1≥x+1≥1$
$-2≥x≥0$

I thought that by doing so, I will be able to get some information about the numerator, however, I just confused myself.

Would anybody be kind enough to set me on the right direction?

Comment: Hint:  $$| \sin x |\leq 1$$ and $$x \leq |x|+1$$

Comment: You should try to get bounds on x/(|x|+1 ). Also note that sine is bounded by 1

Comment: Further hint: Show that $$\frac{x}{|x|+1} < 1$$

Comment: Thanks for the great tips guiys! I have tried to prove it and posted my solution below. Is this considered to be a valid justification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything seems to check out. What you essentially have done is this:

since we want to show $\frac{x*\sin(x)}{|x|+1}$ is bounded we take its absolute value so we have

|$\frac{x*\sin(x)}{|x|+1}$| = $\frac{|x*\sin(x)|}{||x|+1|}$ = $\frac{|x|*\|sin(x)|}{||x|+1|}$
By what you said about |$\sin(x)$| $\le$ 1 we get that

$\frac{|x|*\|sin(x)|}{||x|+1|}$ $\le$ $\frac{|x|}{||x|+1|}$

Since |x| $\le$ |x| + 1, we get that $\frac{1}{|x|}$ $\ge$ $\frac{1}{|x|+1}$ which shows us that

$\frac{|x|}{||x|+1|}$ $\le$ $\frac{|x|}{|x|}$ = 1

So yes, you have proven that f(x) := $\frac{x*\sin(x)}{|x|+1}$ is bounded

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the great hints guys! I have tried proving this statement like so:

${x\sin(x)\over |x| + 1}$ 
$|{x\sin(x)\over |x| + 1|}|$

${|x\sin(x)|\over |x| + 1|}$

${|x|*|sin(x)|\over |x| + 1|}$

Since ${|xsin(x)|≤1}$ we can multiply the inequality $xsin(x)≤1$ by ${|x|\over |x| + 1}$ on both sides which will produce an expression that is still ≤1.

like so:

${|x|*1\over |x| + 1}≤1$ 
${|x|\over |x| + 1}≤1$ 
Is this sufficient to prove the statement is bounded?

Comment: "Since $|x\sin x|\le 1$" looks like a typo. I think what you meant is something like $|x\sin x|=|x|\cdot |\sin x|\le |x|\cdot 1=|x|.$ BTW you can use \cdot for a "multiplication dot".